# Cobol testing framework for gnu cobol on x86_64 machine?

Tags: cobol

I am aware of some existing cobol testing frameworks but, non of those are suitable for my case, what i looking for is:

1. testing framework for gnu cobol on x86_64 machine
2. readable and understandable documentation for this framework
3. free of costs
4. If none of those requirements are met, than tell me where i can find github project which is going to this direction so i can collaborate with them and produce high quality testing framework, because in Germany we have a lot of Cobol code which must be maintained and tested.

Windows or Linux environment would be ok.

Comment: Not free so not posting as an answer:  See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/COBOLTestCoverage.html  This tool does not dictate how you write your tests; you can use any technique you like.  But it does determine what gets tested, and it will do this for very large codebases.  The specific tool offered is for IBM Enterprise COBOL; the tool style can be easily adapted to other COBOL dialect (e.g., GNUCOBOL).

Comment: Is this tool only for coverage, i mean the test itself written in Cobol then?
Basically  i need a tool which can get data from mainframe environment , after running some tests and the output should be in plain format, from which i can write an application for my workstation in Java and then know what actually did fail ;)

Comment: The tool operates on mainframe Enterprise COBOL program.  Apply the tool to instrument the program; this happens on your workstation. Compile the program (obviously on the MF), run your tests (don't care what you write them in  but obviously they have to invoke the COBOL programs).  At end of test runs, the instrumented program writes out coverage data to some MF file.  Transfer that file back to your PC and get the display you see at the site.  The test converage tool doesn't care if  your test failed or not; it tells you what code the test executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is often that for *unit* testing you need programs that work with a defined input/output, have no user-interaction and ideally covers one topic. I should either have no file-io or could work with a testing set of files (which you'd then have to create/maintain) or uses SQL without a `COMMIT` (enabling you to start a transaction before running the test case and have the data not altered outside of the testcase this way). If this is done / possible... (note: even moving a part of the core application and/or utility copybooks to a "testable" base and testing those is a *lot* better than only manual tests)

The testing frameworks you likely want to have a look at:

- [COBOLUnit](https://sites.google.com/site/cobolunit/) "A simple, open source Unit testing framework to write and run repeatable tests in COBOL" (the "old player")
- [gcblunit](https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/gcblunit) "Simple Unit Testing for GnuCOBOL" with reports in JUnit format
- [cobol-unit-test](https://github.com/neopragma/cobol-unit-test) "Unit testing framework for batch COBOL programs"
- [Cobol Check](https://github.com/openmainframeproject/cobol-check) "A testing framework for COBOL applications" from the Open Mainframe Project under active development

An alternative would be to use autotest (as GnuCOBOL does for its internal testsuite) to write the test cases or manually do it via makefiles.

If you want code-coverage checked as well and use GnuCOBOL - just pass `-A --coverage -Q --coverage` to `cobc` when compiling the programs and you can use the gcov toolset to inspect the coverage (but you'd want to do this with a secondary set of binaries to not write coverage files outside of testing).

Comment: This really helpful, since my initial post is almost 4 years , well it shows that Cobol never dies.